# Animate programmatically added subviews

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, class, subview

I've setup an own class(custom UIView).
I'am adding two of these customViews to my UIView as subviews.
So now the question araises: How do I animate the subviews?

```
myCustomView *myCustomViewInstance = [[myCustomView alloc] initWithText:@"myText"]];
    [self.viewContainer addSubview:myCustomViewInstance];

myCustomView *myCustomViewInstance2 = [[myCustomView alloc] initWithText:@"myText2"]];
    [self.viewContainer addSubview:myCustomViewInstance2];
```

Normally I would animate uiviews with:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
self.viewContainer = CGRectMake(20,20,320,460);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

In this case that doesn't work because I am animating the view not the subviews. I also can not acess the subviews directly because of the local declaration. Any Ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `tag` (an integer) on your subviews and retrieve them again with `[self.viewContainer viewWithTag:]`. Then animate as you do with the `viewContainer`.

Comment: thanks works great :)
To add multiple Subviews whcih is the best way?